# Changing single quotes to double quotes with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to change all single quotes to double quotes in a string (unless the single quote occurs in the middle of a word). Yet my code doesn't work correctly on an example string:

```
let r = /(\W)'|'(\W)|^'|'$/g;
let s = "'ble' 'bla' aren't"
s.replace(r, "$1\"$2");
```

What the code returns is:

```
""ble" 'bla" aren't"
```

so the opening quote of 'bla" is a single quote. I don't know why that is. Any ideas as to why my solution doesn't work?

Answer (score 5):

Your solution doesn't work because of overlapping. In `e' 'b`, `'(\W)` matches `'`(quote + space), the space is consumed then the following quote (just before `b` cannot be match because there is no non-word before it.

Replace the single quote only when preceeded or followed by a non-wordboundary:

```js
let r = /\B'|'\B/g;
let s = "'ble' 'bla' aren't"
s = s.replace(r, "\"");
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since regex is not very flexible, you can try replace multiple times, I can do that by replace 2 times

```
let r = /([^a-z])'(\w)/g;
let s = "'ble' 'bla' aren't"
s = s.replace(r, "$1\"$2");
s.replace(/(\w)'([^a-z])/g,"$1\"$2");
```

Comment: I think you have the best answer, I have never known there is \B in regex, I have already voted for you  :)

Comment: Thank you, but your regex produces the same result as OP.

Answer (score -1):

The proper use of straight double " and single ' quotes do not belong in properly punctuated text -- they are actually used in code. [Curly double “ ” and single ‘ ’ quotes (a.k.a. smart quotes) should be used instead](http://smartquotesforsmartpeople.com/). Just going by context provided by example in OP having the need to keep apostrophe means that the text is content and not code:

How is: "'ble' 'bla' aren't"
going to be: ""ble" "bla" aren't" 
without conflict?

The double quotes within need to be escaped or outer quotes replaced by backticks if the line is within code. If it's just continent then it's probably grammatically incorrect (don't know for sure)?

The following demo will replace straight double and single quotes with their curly/smart counterparts. It replaces a straight single quote with a curly/smart right single quote ’ **when its *not* preceded by a space, `^`, `|`, `[`, `-`,—,/,`(`,`\`,`[`,`{`,`"`, or `]` which is a predicate for a closing quote or an apostrophe**.

You can remove the statements that you don't need.

```js
let str = document.querySelector('main').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = smarten(str);

function smarten(str) {
  // Opening single quote
  str = str.replace(/(^|[-—/(\[{"\s])'/g, "$1\u2018");
  // Closing single quote and apostrophe
  str = str.replace(/'/g, "\u2019");
  // Opening double quote
  str = str.replace(/(^|[-—/(\[{‘\s])"/g, "$1\u201c");
  // Closing double quote
  str = str.replace(/"/g, "\u201d");
  return str;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>From Sun Tzu's <i>The Art of War</i>, "If you know both yourself and your enemy, you can win numerous (literally, 'a hundred') battles without jeopardy."</p>
</main>
<output></output>
```